# Could a Half-Veela be Black/Mixed?

Tags: harry-potter, fan-fiction

I have found on multiple sources that Veela have pearly white skin, but if a black wizard and a Veela have a child, could the child still be mixed? Or would he/she still have to have "pearly white" skin? I'm not too sure if I should just wing it and say it doesn't matter, or if I should make my character as canonically correct as possible.

Comment: If your multiple sources are user-content-generated sites like Wikia (and those quoting Wikia), please be careful. Wikia is well known to contain glaring errors, notably results of logical fallacies like **overgeneralization** (we only know of ONE half-Veela in canon, and Rowling never spoke about general color skin, just Fleur's. Then, *someone* on user-content-generated Wikia, can go and turn that detail into generic yet not logically valid "Half-Veela have white skin").

Comment: I would strongly expect them to inherit a slightly darker complexion. We see three more "veela cousins" at the rear of the tent in HP:DH1 and they don't appear to be [identically white-skinned](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/c/ce/Veela_HPDH.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160712185829).

Comment: @Valorum - is that in the movie? (If so, insert witty Hermione quip)

Answer (score 9):

## Since we don't know that much about Veela, anything's possible.

Since we don't really know that much about Veela, I'm going to say yes, just based on genetics. The only example we have is Fleur, who is... totally white. That doesn't mean that if the human was African, that the child would be totally white - probably not.

AFAIK, we don't even know if *Veela* can be black - why wouldn't they be? An absence of proof is not proof of absence.

This is basically all we know (from the HP Wikia):

> Veela have been known to marry wizards, although it is unknown whether any have married Muggles. Children of these unions are half-Veela, and they will inherit magical ability from their fathers and beauty and charm from their mothers. Veela traits seem to persist for at least a few generations (examples being Apolline Delacour, and her daughters Fleur and Gabrielle).

So, to sum up:

## We don't know.

Comment: Is the plural "veela?"

Comment: @CHEESE think so